# Agrupar Dados de um SELECT utilizando o parâmetro de DATA

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Tenho o Seguinte Cenário:

Estou obtendo um SELECT, onde cada registro contém a coordenada e a data de criação deste Registro.
Gostaria de exibir por DATA a quantidade de coordenadas obtidas daquele DIA.

Exemplo do SELECT:

```
[{"id":"2","dataCriacao":"2021-03-17 ","latlng":"-23.550829,-46.2008791"},
{"id":"9","dataCriacao":"2021-03-17 ","latlng":"-23.5507955,-46.2008757"},
{"id":"11","dataCriacao":"2021-03-17 ","latlng":"-23.5582206,-46.1995978"},
{"id":"6","dataCriacao":"2021-03-15 ","latlng":"-23.5508117,-46.2008772"},
{"id":"7","dataCriacao":"2021-03-15 ","latlng":"-23.550829,-46.2008791"},
{"id":"8","dataCriacao":"2021-03-15 ","latlng":"-23.550855,-46.2008978"},
{"id":"1","dataCriacao":"2021-03-14 ","latlng":"-23.550829,-46.2008791"}]
```

Gostaria de exibir com base da DATA exemplo :

```
Data : 2021-03-17 Coordenadas : -23.550829,-46.2008791/-23.5507955,-46.2008757/-23.5582206,-46.1995978
Data : 2021-03-15 Coordenadas : -23.5508117,-46.2008772/-23.550829,-46.2008791/-23.550855,-46.2008978
Data : 2021-03-14 Coordenadas : -23.550829,-46.2008791
```

Porém não estou sabendo como realizar esta concatenação.
Estou obtendo os dados via SELECT no PHP e exibindo no JavaScript e HTML.

Poderiam me auxiliar os dar uma Luz de qual recurso utilizar neste caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia agrupar no `PHP` ou no `javascript`.

No `javascript` poderia agrupar usando [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

**"Data : 2021-03-17 Coordenadas : -23.550829,-46.2008791/-23.5507955,-46.2008757/-23.5582206,-46.1995978"** esse formato deve ser um exemplo (como `json` ele é inválido), pode usar o `reduce` para agrupar por data e associar um array com as coordenadas gerando um novo json com formato válido, assim por exemplo:

```js
var dados = [
   {
      "id":"2",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-17 ",
      "latlng":"-23.550829,-46.2008791"
   },
   {
      "id":"9",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-17 ",
      "latlng":"-23.5507955,-46.2008757"
   },
   {
      "id":"11",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-17 ",
      "latlng":"-23.5582206,-46.1995978"
   },
   {
      "id":"6",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-15 ",
      "latlng":"-23.5508117,-46.2008772"
   },
   {
      "id":"7",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-15 ",
      "latlng":"-23.550829,-46.2008791"
   },
   {
      "id":"8",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-15 ",
      "latlng":"-23.550855,-46.2008978"
   },
   {
      "id":"1",
      "dataCriacao":"2021-03-14 ",
      "latlng":"-23.550829,-46.2008791"
   }
];

var result = dados.reduce(function (acumulador, item) {
    var key = item["dataCriacao"];

    // verifica se já agrupou pela data, senão cria um novo objeto
    if (!acumulador[key]) {
      acumulador[key] = { "coordenadas":  [] };
    }
    
    // adiciona à data, propriedade "coordenadas" o valor de latlng
    acumulador[key].coordenadas.push(item.latlng);
    return acumulador;
  }, {});

// resultado agrupado
console.log(result);
```